# How can i find with android espresso web all the elements in Class name and choose what i need

Tags: java, android-espresso

I am trying to find the currency value in some class, the web using the class in couple of places. In web console I found it like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("casino-gaming-balance-replacer")[1].innerText
```

and get the value "£ 93.37"

In the android studio I used:

```
onWebView().withNoTimeout().withElement(findElement(Locator.CLASS_NAME, "casino-gaming-balance-replacer")).check(webMatches(getText(), containsString("X")));
```

but got nothing.

I want to see all elements in the class and save it in "String = Temp". How can i do it?

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to use **Locator.XPATH**
Just copy it from browser Inspector:

[image]